# Loading nodelets built in different machines to a single manager

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, nodelet, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working on a project with Ubuntu 16.04 and `kinetic` where I have two `catkin` workspaces: one for building the `iai_kinect2` package for handling KinectOne data reading, and another for building my own packages for image processing. I used to build them separately and run them in different `docker` containers, whereas `roscore` is running in the host PC. In this fashion, each container sources its own `setup.bash` file, so the `iai_kinect2` nodelets cannot find the libraries for launching my own nodelets, which have been built in another container.

I am wondering if there is a way of launching `nodelet`s from different `docker`containers / machines onto the same `manager` without having to source the bash file of each build in the host machine.

Right now I have placed both packages in the same container as a workaround, but I would like to be able to separate them as the project I work on requires different libraries for different packages, therefore using several docker containers to launch the nodes from each package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318009/loading-nodelets-built-in-different-machines-to-a-single-manager/) by [jgallostra](https://answers.ros.org/users/40338/jgallostra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As commented by @gvdhoorn:

Nodelets are stored on disk as shared libraries. If the manager process cannot access the shared library, it cannot load the nodelet.

In this particular case, what could work is clever mounting of directories from the ROS workspace containing the nodelets into the container that wants to load them (don't forget the metadata that is also need, ie: `package.xml`). But depending on what those nodelets exactly do this may not work, as all the dependencies of those nodelets would also need to be accessible.

This issue has to do more with "dependency hell" rather than `nodelet`s. If workspace A needs a certain set of dependencies, and workspace B needs another incompatible set of dependencies, using artefacts from workspace A in processes from workspace B is not going to work.

---

Originally posted by [jgallostra](https://answers.ros.org/users/40338/jgallostra/) with karma: 30 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jgallostra](https://answers.ros.org/users/40338/jgallostra/) on 2019-03-11**:
Btw, should I close the question now that it has been answered?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-11**:
No. Just mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark.